# Get filtered array using Regex

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I have the `input` array as follows.

```js
const input = [
  '_rels', 'item1.xml',
  'item2.xml', 'item3.xml',
  'item4.xml', 'item5.xml',
  'item6.xml', 'item7.xml',
  'itemProps1.xml', 'itemProps2.xml',
  'itemProps3.xml', 'itemProps4.xml',
  'itemProps5.xml', 'itemProps6.xml',
  'itemProps7.xml'
]
```

Array can include any string.

I would like to filter the array of the `item{number}.xml`, not including the `itemProps{number}.xml`.

The expected result would be:

```
const output = [
'item1.xml', 'item2.xml', 'item3.xml', 'item4.xml', 'item5.xml', 'item6.xml', 'item7.xml'
]
```

Comment: Why regex? Just search for `itemProps`.

Comment: there could be many other non `item` prefix elements in the array.

Comment: Then keep all elements that start with `item` but not `itemProps`. Still doesn't require a regular expression.

Comment: if i filter the elements that start with `item` ,then `itemProps1.xml` will be also included in the result, but i just want to `item1.xml, item2.xml, ...` only.

Comment: You've missed the _"... **but not** `itemProps`"_ part of my comment

Comment: there could be any elements, even itemblablabl.xml, and i need to exclude them.

Comment: You're explicitly asking for `item` and `itemProps` in the question. How are we (am I) supposed to know that there can be other `item*` entries? -> _"How to keep only the `item{Number}.xml` entries from input array?"_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `RegExp.prototype.test()` and `Array.prototype.filter` methods for gaining your result.

```js
 const input = [
  '_rels', 'item1.xml',
  'item2.xml', 'item3.xml',
  'item4.xml', 'item5.xml',
  'item6.xml', 'item7.xml',
  'itemProps1.xml', 'itemProps2.xml',
  'itemProps3.xml', 'itemProps4.xml',
  'itemProps5.xml', 'itemProps6.xml',
  'itemProps7.xml'
];

const res = input.filter(item => /^item\d+\.xml$/i.test(item));

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of regex combine with `Array.prototype.reduce` method like this

```js
const input = [
  '_rels', 'item1.xml',
  'item2.xml', 'item3.xml',
  'item4.xml', 'item5.xml',
  'item6.xml', 'item7.xml',
  'itemProps1.xml', 'itemProps2.xml',
  'itemProps3.xml', 'itemProps4.xml',
  'itemProps5.xml', 'itemProps6.xml',
  'itemProps7.xml'
]
const regExPattern = /itemProps\d+\.xml/
const result = input.reduce((acc, current) => {
  if(regExPattern.test(current) === false){
    return acc.concat(current);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Which is just a complicated version of Sajeebs `.filter()` answer (and that's also missing the `_rels` entry)

Comment: I made change to take only items which start with `item` and contain any number of digit followed by `.xml`